# Z-Index div hover overlay issues with [windows] Webkit (Safari, Opera, etc)

Tags: html, css, windows, webkit, overlay

**Edit: This ONLY occurs on Windows Webkit, does not occur on Macs**

I am trying to set up a grid with fixed sized cells with a background image.  When you hover, the background image and height of cell is changed/increased and overlays the row below it.

I tried a few ways to create this idea and came down to that a table with z-index applied to the row would work the best.

My issue, as the title says, is that I have this working in IE/FF, but for whatever reason webkit doesn't seem to care about the z-index on the row settings.

I should note that inside each grid is the jquery cycle plugin which I don't think affects anything, but I'm having some issues with pausing the cycle plugin in webkit as well.

**html of the table and two rows**

```
<div id="girlcontent">
     <table class="girltable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
            <td class="girlrow" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1a.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1b.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1c.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext">
                    <div class="girltext">Butters</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle2"> 
                  <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                  <img src="img/girls/1c.jpg" alt="image" />
                  <img src="img/girls/1d.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext2">
                    <div class="girltext">CandyCanes</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle3"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1e.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1b.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1f.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext3">
                    <div class="girltext">Tandy</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle4"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1b.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1e.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
              <div id="gctext4">
                    <div class="girltext">Dancer</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="girlrow2" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle5"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1f.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1e.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext5">
                    <div class="girltext">Sam</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow2" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle6"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1d.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1e.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext6">
                    <div class="girltext">Tina</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow2" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle7"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1f.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1d.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext7">
                    <div class="girltext">Natalie</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="girlrow2" valign="top">
            <div class="girlbox"> 
             <div class="girlplace" id="girlcycle8"> 
                 <img src="img/girls/1b.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1e.jpg" alt="image" />
                    <img src="img/girls/1g.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div>
                <div id="gctext8">
                    <div class="girltext">Lana</div>
                    <div class="girltextsm">info</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
       </table>
</div>
```

**CSS for the content area/background/etc**

```
#girlcontent {
width:860px;
background-color:#000;
}

#girlspace {
background-color:#000;
padding-bottom:35px;
width:860px;
}

.girlbox {
background-image:url(../img/girlsbacka.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:264px;
width:194px;
margin:10px;
z-index:0;
position:absolute;
}

.girlbox:hover {
background-image:url(../img/girlsbackb.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:325px;
width:194px;
}

.girltable {
width:860px;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
}

.girlrow {
height:264px;
z-index:3;
position:relative;
}


.girlrow2 {
 height:264px;
 z-index:2;
 position:relative;
}
```

**Javascript for the area, there's more based upon the ID's**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#girlcycle').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
delay:  -250
});
$('#girlcycle').cycle('pause');
$('#gctext').hide();
$('#girlcycle').hover(function() { 
    $('#girlcycle').cycle('resume', true);
    $('#gctext').show();
});
 $('#girlcycle').mouseleave(function() { 
    $('#girlcycle').cycle('pause');
    $('#gctext').hide();
});
```

If anyone has any idea why this wouldn't work in webkit, I'd be grateful for any help that you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into these kinds of issues [as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832793/css-z-index-issue-works-in-firefox-but-not-safari). Here's what I found out:

According to the [CSS 2.1 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position):

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

I'm assuming that Firefox implements it one way, and WebKit implements it a different way and both are correct since it is undefined. The moral of the story here is not to specify a position on table elements.