# CSS z-index issue: works in Firefox, but not Safari?

Tags: css, firefox, safari, z-index

I am trying to show a specific table row on top of an overlay. It's working in Firefox, but not Safari. I don't understand how that can be possible since Firefox and Safari usually render these types of things the same.

```
<body>

    <style>
        .overlay {
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:#000;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>

    <table>
        <tr style="position:relative; z-index:1000; background:#fff;">
            <td>show this one on top</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Show these below</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Show these below</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Show these below</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="overlay"></div>

</body>
```

What could it be that is causing this difference between Safari and Firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CSS 2.1 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position):

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

I'm assuming that Firefox implements it one way, and WebKit implements it a different way and both are correct since it is undefined. The moral of the story here is not to specify a position on table elements.

I was able to get it to work by wrapping the contents of each table cell with a `div` and positioning the div. I also moved the overlay inside of the table row that I was targeting (not sure if that was necessary).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position:relative; z-index:1000;">
                Displays on top in both Safari and Firefox
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position:relative; z-index:1000;">
                Displays on top in both Safari and Firefox
            </div>
            <span class="overlay"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Displays below overlay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Displays below overlay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Displays below overlay</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Safari and Firefox use different rendering engines, which would explain why they are behaving differently in this case. Safari uses WebKit, while Firefox uses Gecko.

Comment: Obviously. The question is in what way is Firefox rendering it differently, and what do I need to change so that Safari matches the way it looks in Firefox?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've done some testing, and can't figure out how to make your solution work in Safari. It looks like a td (or tr) can't be displayed with a larger z-index than its parent table in Safari. The only solution I can think of right now would be to split this into two different tables (with the same width)... One with a z-index above the overlay, and one with a z-index below it.