# webkit-filter greyscale with overlaying DIV

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit, grayscale

I have an issue with a greyscale filter over a background image on a div http://jsfiddle.net/wZvjH/3/ which on hover `.bg` changes to color.

However, why is the `.left1` and `.left2` in greyscale too even though i have a `z-index` applied? that wasn't the plan. How can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Z-Index div hover overlay issues with \[windows\] Webkit (Safari, Opera, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780697/z-index-div-hover-overlay-issues-with-windows-webkit-safari-opera-etc)

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Chrome/Mac.

Comment: If the issue is WebKit related, then it is likely the same on Mac, Windows, Linux, iOS. WebKit is the rendering engine used in Chrome on all these platforms (well, until recently, when Google decided to use Blink engine instead, but I believe it's still related to your issue). You may verify by trying the same thing in Firefox and IE if (use an online IE renderer if you don't have access).

Comment: OK. I think i'm missing the point of that post, it suggesting its the position property thats causing my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply a filter to an element, that filter applies to all its children too. There's no way to turn that off. You'd need to move the left and left2 out of the hierarchy such that they are siblings of the main `<div>` if you don't want the filter applied on them.

Comment: Hmm.. the problem with taking it out of the hierachy now is that the DIV doesn't automatically change it's height.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZekNx/1/ any suggestions?